# Codec not found for requested operation: [list<watson.destination_intent> <-> scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon]

Tags: cassandra, user-defined-types

I am getting CodecNotFoundException when trying to use the list of UserDefinedType
I have already registered the codec for the UDT, this is happening when I am trying to use the list of UDT

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.CodecNotFoundException: Codec not found for requested operation: [list<watson.destination_intent> <-> scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon]
at com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry.notFound(CodecRegistry.java:741)
at com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry.createCodec(CodecRegistry.java:602)
at com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry.findCodec(CodecRegistry.java:582)
at com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry.codecFor(CodecRegistry.java:507)
at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractGettableByIndexData.codecFor(AbstractGettableByIndexData.java:77)
at com.datastax.driver.core.BoundStatement.bind(BoundStatement.java:201)
at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultPreparedStatement.bind(DefaultPreparedStatement.java:126)
at com.expedia.www.watson.flink.jobs.CassandraListOutputFormat.writeRecord(TravelerProfileLoadJob.scala:218)
at com.expedia.www.watson.flink.jobs.CassandraListOutputFormat.writeRecord(TravelerProfileLoadJob.scala:173)
at com.expedia.www.watson.sdk.flink.outputs.RateLimitingOutputFormat.writeRecord(RateLimitingOutputFormat.scala:36)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.DataSinkTask.invoke(DataSinkTask.java:192)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:642)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the issue was with the scala and java conversions. 
Since the driver is written in java and I was using scala to pass the list, it was failing while trying to create the codec on the fly.
Once I change my list to java.util.list, It started working.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

val list: List[String] = InputString.split(",").toList

val javaList = list.asJava

Ex: connector.withSessionDo { session => session.execute(session.prepare(selectQuery).setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.LOCAL_ONE).bind(javaList, field)) }
```